# Can application in untyped lambda calculus be seen as the uncurried unit of some monad?

Tags: ct.category-theory, monads, lambda-calculus

Simply typed lambda calculus in one type variable in a Cartesian closed category $\mathbf{C}$ can be interpreted as a family of Cartesian closed functors (described below, do they have a name?) from the Cartesian closed category $\mathbf{STLC_1}$ of simply typed lambda calculus types with products with one type variable and all terms between them (also described below and does this category have a name?). I will loosely prove that when these functors are endofunctors, they are not monads, and if they were, $\mathbf{STLC_1}$ would be strong enough to interpret untyped lambda calculus. My question is if there is some other category, similar to $\mathbf{STLC_1}$ where the (similar) family of endofunctors are monads, so that untyped lambda calculus can be interpreted in that category.

The objects $s$ of $\mathbf{STLC_1}$ are defined recursively as

$$s \leftarrow a$$
$$s \leftarrow s_1 \times s_2$$
$$s \leftarrow s_2^{s_1}$$

where $a$ denotes the single generator of the lambda calculus, $\times$ denotes categorical product and superscript denotes exponentials in $\mathbf{STLC_1}$.

According to the well known functorial interpretation of simply typed lambda calculus, each pair of types $s_1, s_2 \in \mathbf{STLC_1}$ (s is for signature, CS lingo for lambda types) and each term $t : s_1 \to s_2$ corresponds to a pair of functors $F_1, F_2 \in \mathbf{C}^{op} \times \mathbf{C} \to \mathbf{C}$ and a dinatural transformation between them, typically depicted as a commuting hexagon.

This can be turned into a functor $\operatorname{I} : \mathbf{STLC_1} \times \mathbf{C}^{op} \times \mathbf{C} \to \mathbf{C}$. For each pair of objects $a, b \in \mathbf{C}$, each arrow $f : b \to a$, each pair of types $s_1, s_2 \in \mathbf{STLC_1}$ and each term $t : s_1 \to s_2$, the functor indicates a commuting hexagon in $\mathbf{C}$. With a little imagination (or some kind hearted editor who masters the LaTeX array environment) it can be depicted:

$$ 
\operatorname{I}\  s_1\ a\ b
\stackrel{\operatorname{I}  s_1\ f\ b}{\to} 
\operatorname{I}\  s_1\ b\ b
\stackrel{\operatorname{I}\ t\ b\ b}{\to}
\operatorname{I}\  s_2\ b\ b
\stackrel{\operatorname{I}\ s_2\ b\ f}{\to}
\operatorname{I}\  s_2\ b\ a 
$$

$$ \operatorname{I}\  s_1\ a\ b
\stackrel{\operatorname{I}\ s_1\ a\ f}{\to} 
\operatorname{I}\  s_1\ a\ a
\stackrel{\operatorname{I}\ t\ a\ a}{\to}
\operatorname{I}\  s_2\ a\ a
\stackrel{\operatorname{I}\ s_2\ f\ a}{\to}
\operatorname{I}\  s_2\ b\ a 
$$

Objects in a position where an arrow is expected denotes the identity morphism of that object, e. g. $\operatorname{I}\  s_1\ f\ b = \operatorname{I}\  id_{s_1}\ f\ id_b$. If we set $b = a$ and $f = id_a$, the hexagon is collapsed into two objects $a_{s_1} = \operatorname{I}\  a\ a\ s_1$ and $a_{s_2} = \operatorname{I}\  a\ a\ s_2$ an arrow $f_{a, t} = \operatorname{I}\  t\ a\ a : (\operatorname{I}\  s_2\ a\ a) \to (\operatorname{I}\  s_2 \ a\ a)$. For each choice of $a$ in this way, we get a Cartesian closed functor functor $\operatorname{T_a} \in \mathbf{STLC_1} \to \mathbf{C}$.

Since $\mathbf{STLC_1}$ is also Cartesian closed, each type $s$ can be used to indicate an endofunctor $\operatorname{T_s} \in \mathbf{STLC_1}\to \mathbf{STLC_1}$. Capital $\operatorname{T}$ is usually reserved for endofunctors that are monads, but the functors $\operatorname{T_s}$ are not, or at least not in general. The existence of such a family of monads would imply $\mathbf{STLC_1}$ would be strong enough to interpret untyped lambda calculus. Since the Cartesian closed category $\mathbf{C}$ by definition has all the structure of $\mathbf{STLC_1}$, such monads would imply $\mathbf{C}$, in general, could also implement untyped lambda calculus (I think). Since this is clearly not the case, the endofunctors $\operatorname{T_s}& are not monads (I think).

For any types $s_1, s_2 \in \mathbf{STLC_1}$ and any two terms $t_1 : s_2^{s_1}$, $t_2 : s_1$, the universal arrow $eval_{s_1, s_2} : (s_2^{s_1} \times s_1) \to s_2$ of exponentiation in $\mathbf{STLC_1}$ evaluates application of terms. It is the uncurried version of the identity function $id_{s_1, s_2}: (s_1 \to s_2) \to s_1 \to s_2$. With $\pi_1$ and $\pi_2$ as product projections, it can be implemented as

$$\lambda p. (\pi_1 p) (\pi_2 p)$$

This is not enough to evaluate untyped lambda calculus. For example, in the exponential operator for Church numerals

$$\lambda n . \lambda m . m\ n,$$

the $m$ cannot be directly applied to $n$, because $m$ expects a first argument of type

$$a \to a$$

and $n$ has type

$$(a \to a) \to a \to a.$$

To evaluate the application $\lambda n . \lambda m . m\ n$, $m$ needs to be of the type

$$((a \to a) \to a \to a) \to (a \to a) \to a \to a = \operatorname{T_{a \to a}} ((a \to a) \to a \to a)$$

This equality implies we need a new evaluation  function

$$eval_{a \to a} = \lambda p. (\operatorname{T_{a \to a}} (\pi_1\ p)) (\pi_2\ p)$$

The application $(\operatorname{T_{a \to a}} (\pi_1\ p)) (\pi_2\ p)$ will work, because $T_{a \to a}$ is Cartesian closed, so it will, in particular, preserve exponentials and their evaluation. In the example, this becomes

$$\lambda\ n : ((a \to a) \to a \to a) . \lambda\ m : ((a \to a) \to a \to a). (\operatorname{T_{a \to a}}\ m)\ n$$

which has the correct types.

In general, any type $s$ gives a functor $\operatorname{T_s}$ with a evaluation-function:

$$\lambda p. (\operatorname{T_s} (\pi_1\ p)) (\pi_2\ p).$$

If this function existed, it would be the uncurried version of a function

$$\mu_s : s_2^{s_1} \to (\operatorname{T_s} s_2)^{\operatorname{T_s} s_2} = s_2^{s_1} \to \operatorname{T_s} (s_2^{s_1}).$$

The equality of types is due to the Cartesian closedness of $\operatorname{T_s}$.

If $\operatorname{T_s}$ was a monad and $\mu_s$ was the unit at $s_2^{s_1}$, it would behave exactly as expected. The problem is that those arrows do not exist in $\mathbf{STLC_1}$. Therefore, I am hoping to find a category very similar to $\mathbf{STLC_1}$, but one which has the required unit arrows. Hints might be if these monads arise in some bigger category as adjunctions with $\mathbf{STLC_1}$, or if arrows should be defined to also include $\operatorname{T_s}$.

The most annoying thing is that there is such a mapping, it is just a set theoretic function, not a lambda calculus one. For all types $s_1, s_2 \in \mathbf{STLC_1}$, $\operatorname{T_s}$ takes each term (arrow) $t : s_1 \to s_2$ to an arrow $\operatorname{T_s} t : (\operatorname{T_s}\ s_1) \to (\operatorname{T_s}\ s_2)$. These arrows correspond to points in the corresponding exponential objects $s_2^{s_1}$ and $(\operatorname{T_s}\ s_2)^{\operatorname{T_s}\ s_1}$, so  $\operatorname{T_s}$ gives a mapping from points in $s_2^{s_1}$ to points in $(\operatorname{T_s}\ s_2)^{\operatorname{T_s}\ s_1}$, but $\mathbf{STLC_1}$ has no corresponding arrow.

So, what I am hoping to find is a category with similar properties as $\mathbf{STLC_1}$, but with the desired units, but really, right now any thoughts or hints are appreciated. Maybe some free category of lambda calculus/cartesian closedness?

Comment: There seems to be broken LaTeX in the middle of the question, but more importantly, what is the question, precisely? It would help if you could write an abridged version of your question that people can read quickly. Experience shows that very verbose questions attract little attention.

Comment: Are you, by any chance, saying "signatures" instead of "types"? That would explain why I am so confused. It's not called the "simply singatured $\lambda$-calculus"...